# Run one of two scripts based on the outcome of a check?

Tags: script, group-policy, parameters

I have two GPO scripts that, in a nutshell:

1. Close any existing instances of Chrome.
2. Open a new instance of Chrome.
3. Navigate to a webpage.

The only thing is that one script checks the location of Chrome in "Program Files" directory, "Program Files (x86)" directory. Since multiple PC's use this script, it's going to be 50/50 on whether or not this works.

Is there a way, perhaps using script parameters in GPManagement, to run one s riot or the other, based on the validity of the Chrome.exe directory?

Comment: Couldn't you do both checks directly within the same script?

Comment: You may certainly make your script evolve, but you don't show us what your scripts do.